# Mysql fetch data with count and between date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my table structure. I have to fetch the zip_code's range as per they created in database table in given between date.

[image]

For example in the given between dates are 4-aug-14 to 9-aug-14 i need follwing result

zip  number

90620   10

90621   5

How i write mysql query for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IS this you want the result [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f90c/2/0)

try

```
SELECT zip
    , COUNT(1) AS count
FROM table1
WHERE created BETWEEN '2014-08-04 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-08 23:59:59'
GROUP BY zip
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
Select zip, count(*) from table_name where created between 'from_date' and 'to_date' group by zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT zip
    , COUNT(id) AS count
FROM [table]
WHERE created BETWEEN '2014-08-04 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-08 23:59:59'
GROUP BY zip
ORDER BY count DESC
```